# replacing a word with two words when the word starts on 7th position/column

Tags: notepad++

Hi I have a file with many lines like shown below

```
echo $DAT_OUT
echo $DAT_IN
echo $FILE_IN
echo $FILE_OUT
```

I want to use notepad plus plus to make the above lines to look like

```
echo dat_out=$DAT_OUT
echo dat_in=$DAT_IN
echo file_in=$FILE_IN
echo file_out=$FILE_OUT
```

and so on...
Is this doable in notepad plus pluS?

Comment: Not the right place for this. Anyways, I doubt it can do a search replace for that format. You could write a small PHP file that will do exactly what you want, run it, wala all the changes are complete.

Comment: how is this not the right place? I used notepad++ as a tag. There are many NPP questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the job with:

Find what: `echo \$(.+)`
Replace with: `echo \L$1\E=\$$1`

Where `\L$1\E` lowercases the variable name.